# assigning equation number in \[ \] environment

Tags: equations

I am new to latex so forgive me if this is a silly question.I want to assign equation a number and I have defined an equation like this-

```
\[
    I^e(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}
        1 & \text{if edge is detected at pixel I(x,y)}\\
        0 & \text{otherwise}\\
        \end{array}\right.
\]
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) change `\[... \] ` to `\begin{equation}.... \end{equation} `

Comment: ...also consider using a `cases` environment (from [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)).

Answer (score 5):

Use the  `equation` environment, and, simpler, the `cases*` environment (load `mathtools`, an extension of `amsmath`). Here is a code:

```
\begin{equation}
I^e(x,y) = \begin{cases*}
        1 & if edge is detected at pixel $I(x,y)$\\
        0 & otherwise
        \end{cases*}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: ...sure you can. Use `\tag{<tag>}`...

Comment: Is `$` necessary on left hand side of `cases*` also?

Comment: @Werner: I vaguely remember having had problems with that, but I don't remember what exactly. Perhaps it was in a particular context, or cross-references didn't work.

Comment: @Sigur: the star version (defined by mathtools) leaves math mode in the second column.

Comment: @Bernard, oh, very trick.